# How to properly express "to mess up" in German

Tags: meaning, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

I'm looking for the best way to express "to mess something up" in German. I get the feeling that in English, it is used more widely in German, and hence I have tended to make some mistakes while speaking. However, as usual, dictionaries are of little use. Let me give 3 sentences:

1. You have a great opportunity, but are about to mess it up for yourself.
2. He got in a car accident, and this really messed up his nose. (broken, bloody, etc.)
3. I spilled juice all over the place, which messed up (stained) my shirt.

Now, I THINK the first is the easiest, because this is where the overlap between German and English lies: To mess up/screw up a situation. Thus, I will attempt a translation:

1. > Du hast eine tolle Chance, aber bist gerade dabei, es dir selbst zu vermasseln/versauen.

The other two are what confuse me the most. It seems that *vermasseln* is synonymous with *verbocken*, to screw up/botch a situation, but I am unsure if *versauen* still works? Or if there is a general word that works? I will attempt translations:

2. > Er hatte einen Autounfall, und das hat seine Nase wirklich versaut.
3. > Ich habe den Saft überall verschüttet. Das hat mein Hemd versaut.

Do sentences 2 and 3 work?

Answer (score 3):

*Versauen* is a verb. *Versauen* is colloquial. If you speak / write colloquial you should skip words you do not need to transport the information.

1. > Du hast eine tolle Chance, <del>(du)</del> 'bist aber gerade dabei<del>,</del> es dir <del>selbst</del> zu vermasseln/versauen.
2. > Er hatte einen Autounfall, <del>und</del> das hat seine Nase <del>wirklich</del> versaut.
3. > Ich habe den Saft überall verschüttet. Das hat mein Hemd versaut.

All sentences will work.

Comment: Ich würd ja sagen, *du hast's verkackt* - Aber nee, haste nich.

Comment: @tofro *du hast's verkackt* ist vergangenheitsform, richtig wäre präsenz. *aber du verkackst (sie).*, Aber nee, habsch nich.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that *mess up* seems to be quite universally applicable. While in German *versauen* is a good match, it is on the colloquial level. Other alternatives exist, but are more targeted.

- verderben, the most universal, would work for all of your examples but  the nose. Here ...
- verunstalten would be my choice.
- verhunzen is also quite generic.

Comment: *verunstalten* doesn't fit the first example, *verderben* sounds very weird with the second.

Answer (score 2):

Ich stimme guidot zu, dass die Sätze, bis auf den mit der Nase, in Ordnung sind.

Man könnte in allen Fallen auch "ruinieren" benutzen:

- You have a great opportunity, but are about to mess it up for yourself.

  - Du hattest eine große Chance, bist aber dabei sie Dir zu ruinieren.
- He got in a car accident, and this really messed up his nose. (broken, bloody, etc.)

  - Er hatte einen Autounfall und das hat seine Nase richtig ruiniert.
- I spilled juice all over the place, which messed up (stained) my shirt.

  - Ich habe überall Saft verschüttet, womit ich mein Hemd ruiniert habe.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is not so good. It is better to be more specific, for instance:

*Dabei hat er sich die Nase gebrochen.*

Otherwise, the sentence can be misunderstood.